# How to chain multiple fma operations together for performance?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, fma

Assuming that in some C or C++ code I have a function named `T fma( T a, T b, T c )` that performs 1 multiplication and 1 addition like so `( a * b ) + c` ; how I'm supposed to optimize multiple *mul & add* steps ?

For example my algorithm needs to be implemented with 3 or 4 fma operations chained and summed together, How I can write this is an efficient way and at what part of the syntax or semantics I should dedicate particular attention ?

I also would like some hints on the critical part: avoid changing the rounding mode for the CPU to avoid flushing the cpu pipeline. But I'm quite sure that just using the `+` operation between multiple calls to `fma` shouldn't change that, I'm saying *"quite sure"* because I don't have too many CPUs to test this, I'm just following some logical steps.

My algorithm is something like the total of multiple fma calls

```
fma ( triplet 1 ) + fma ( triplet 2 ) + fma ( triplet 3 )
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking about here.  Presumably this is entirely down to what your particular compiler chooses to do?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth can you outline the part that is unclear ?

Comment: What I just said ;)  It's not clear how to answer this question, because (unless I'm missing something) this is entirely down to your particular compiler and hardware.  I don't see what an generic answer to this question would look like.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ok, `gcc 4.9.0` and an `sse2` capable CPU are my minimum target right now.

Comment: Are you talking about the FMA instructions found on recent AMD and Intel (Haswell) CPUs ?

Comment: @PaulR nope, `gcc` offers an fma builtin for SSE2 plus I also plan to code something in assembly. My focus here is to not screw up the cpu pipeline/cache .

Comment: OK, but since there is no ISA support for this on older x86 what are you hoping to gain ? Using the builtin will just generate separate multiply and add instructions, surely ?

Comment: How about specialising the function using the C99 fma, fmaf and fmal functions from math.h

Comment: @user1937198 it's basically the same, take a look at how this functions from the standard C library are implemented .

Comment: @PaulR are you asking or asserting ? As I said my question is how to write pipeline friendly code, there is 1 more variable with this fma approach, the rounding mode used for the fma itself, I would like to be sure that writing an extra addition between this functions will not screw up the computation, plus I would like to ask if simply chaining together this calls is a good thing for performance.

Comment: OK - I was just trying to understand the problem and the motivation behind it.

Comment: So, have you tried something like the obvious solution that you post and found that it is somehow not acceptable?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm new at this kind of optimizations . I have done my researches on how to write generic FMA code, what gcc and libc are offering, how to use them, but I have never encountered a case where the rounding mode or how the floating point computation is set it's vitally important for the performances of the single function/builtin . I would like to hit the maximum flops available .

Comment: Where does rounding mode come into this? As long as you don't manually mess with rounding modes, the compiler shouldn't either (unless you compile for 32-bit wihtout SSE and you convert float to integer, but SSE has instructions specifically for this purpose). Compile some code, look at the assembler generated, and if there is a problem, provide evidence in your question.

Comment: @user2485710 Its not as calls to math.h functions are treated specially by gcc so the glibc source has nothing to do with the output on platforms where gcc supports fma.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm not sure that the compiler can do that without some fma specific flags or without relaxing the IEEE requirements with `Ofast` for example. You are not mentioning the flags or the settings that you are using in your hypothetical example.

Comment: @user1937198 all I can see is that there are calls to builtin__ functions wrapped into standard library functions . You should explain what you mean with that with an example.

Comment: Its both ways. builtin_fma and fma are treated the same way. They are a single operation in gccs AST so that when gcc reaches expand_builtin in gcc/builtins.c the operation is converted into the fma instruction if it exists. The fma function is only converted into a call to glibc's fma after gcc has determined that the platform does not support fma.

Comment: @user1937198 thanks, but I can't see how this helps me with my question, I was assuming that already with my previous assertions, maybe there was a misunderstanding about this.

Comment: Now I understand. The fma function and compiler optimisations are probably your best bet if you want code that supports multiple cpus. Otherwise, look up the intel/AMD optimisation guide for the architecture.

Comment: Voting to close.  The lengthy trail of comments makes it apparent that the original question is unclear.  The absence of answers hints at that too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark like what ? What you don't get after reading the original question ?

Comment: You might find [this Build 2014 talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/4-587) interesting.

Answer (score 7):

Recently, in Build 2014 Eric Brumer gave a very nice talk on the topic ([see here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/4-587)).
The bottom line of talk was that

> **Using Fused Multiply Accumulate (aka FMA) everywhere hurts performance.**

In Intel CPUs a FMA instruction costs 5 cycles. Instead doing a multiplication (5 cycles) and an addition (3 cycles) costs 8 cycles. Using FMA your are getting two operations in the prize of one (see picture below).

[image]

However, FMA seems not to be the holly grail of instructions. As you can see in the picture below FMA can in certain citations hurt the performance.

[image]

In the same fashion, your case `fma(triplet1) + fma(triplet2) + fma(triplet 3)` costs 21 cycles whereas if you were to do the same operations with out FMA would cost 30 cycles. That's a 30% gain in performance.

Using FMA in your code would demand using [compiler intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx). In my humble opinion though, FMA etc. is not something you should be worried about, unless you are a C++ compiler programmer. If your are not, let the compiler optimization take care of these technicalities. Generally, under such kind of concerns lies the root of all evil (i.e., premature optimization), to paraphrase one of the great ones (i.e., Donald Knuth).

Comment: That’s an rather naive and misleading example. I'm a bit shocked that it came from a compiler engineer.  In performance-critical code, *latency* is rarely the primary bottleneck.  While a*b + c*d has lower latency than fma(a,b,c*d), it requires three µops instead of two, which limits it to 2/3rds the performance in much more common throughput-dominated contexts.  There is a reasonable objection to this transformation, but it is one involving *numerical* details, not performance.