# How can I improve performance compiling for SSE and AVX?

Tags: linux, windows, benchmarking, sse, avx

My new PC has a Core i7 CPU and I am running my benchmarks, including newer versions that use AVX instructions. I have installed Visual Studio 2013 to use a newer compiler, as my last one could not fully compile for full SSE SIMD operation. Below is some code used in one of my benchmarks (MPMFLOPS), and compile and link commands used. Tests were run with the first command to use SSE instructions. When xtra is 16 or less, the benchmark produces 24.4 GFLOPS. CPU runs at 3.9 GHz, so result is good at 6.25 calculations per cycle, compared with maximum of four multiples and four adds. Increasing xtra to greater than 16, produces 2.6 GFLOPS. Reducing words to much lower values makes to difference to speed.

```
 /*  
 Visual Studio 2013
 C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x64

 cl /O2 /Oi /MD /W4 /TP /EHsc /Zi /Fa /c mflops.c
 cl /O2 /Oi /MD /W4 /TP /EHsc /Zi /Fa /arch:AVX /c mflops.c

 link /LARGEADDRESSAWARE mflops.obj CPUasm.obj asmtimeavx.obj 
       BUFFEROVERFLOWU.LIB
 link Includes CPUID information with identification of AVX and timer
 */

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "asmtimeavx.h"
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <malloc.h>



int main()
{
    float   *x;
    float   a = 0.000020f;
    float   b = 0.999980f;
    float   c = 0.000011f;
    float   d = 1.000011f;
    float   e = 0.000012f;
    float   f = 0.999992f;
    float   mflops;
    int i, j;
    int xtra = 16; //  24447 MFLOPS, > 16 around 2600 MFLOPS
    int words = 1000000;

    x = (float *)_aligned_malloc(words * 4, 16);

    for (i = 0; i < words; i++) x[i] = 0.999999f;

    start_time();

    for (j = 0; j < xtra; j++)
    {
            for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
        {
                    x[i] = (x[i] + a)*b - (x[i] + c)*d + (x[i] + e)*f;
            }
    }

    end_time();
    mflops = (float)words * (float)xtra * 8.0f / 1000000.0f / (float)secs;

    printf("%18.8f, %18.8f, %10.7f secs, %8.2f mflops\n\n", x[0], 
            x[words-1], secs, mflops);

    _aligned_free(x);

    return 0;
 }
```

Following shows assembly code generated, where such as mulps is full SIMD with four values in 128 bit registers, with mulss using one floating point number (SISD).

```
Windows SSE
words = 1000000                  
xtra  = 16                             xtra > 16

call    start_time
npad    10
$LL6@main:
mov     rcx, rsi
mov     edx, 125000
npad    8
$LL3@main:
movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rcx]
add     rcx, 32                         movaps  xmm1, xmm2
movaps  xmm2, xmm1                      movaps  xmm0, xmm2
movaps  xmm0, xmm1                      addss   xmm2, xmm8
addps   xmm1, xmm10                     addss   xmm0, xmm6
addps   xmm2, xmm6                      addss   xmm1, xmm4
addps   xmm0, xmm8                      dec     rax
mulps   xmm1, xmm11                     mulss   xmm2, xmm9
mulps   xmm2, xmm7                      mulss   xmm0, xmm7
mulps   xmm0, xmm9                      mulss   xmm1, xmm5
subps   xmm2, xmm0                      subss   xmm1, xmm0
addps   xmm2, xmm1                      addss   xmm1, xmm2
movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx-32], xmm2      movaps  xmm2, xmm1
movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rcx-16]      movaps  xmm0, xmm1
movaps  xmm2, xmm1                      addss   xmm1, xmm8
movaps  xmm0, xmm1                      addss   xmm2, xmm4
addps   xmm2, xmm6                      addss   xmm0, xmm6
addps   xmm0, xmm8                      mulss   xmm1, xmm9
addps   xmm1, xmm10                     mulss   xmm0, xmm7
mulps   xmm2, xmm7                      mulss   xmm2, xmm5
mulps   xmm0, xmm9                      subss   xmm2, xmm0
mulps   xmm1, xmm11                     addss   xmm2, xmm1
subps   xmm2, xmm0                      movaps  xmm3, xmm2
addps   xmm2, xmm1                      movaps  xmm0, xmm2
movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx-16], xmm2      addss   xmm2, xmm8
dec     rdx
jne     SHORT $LL3@main                 More of the same
dec     rbx                             Loop 82 lines
jne     SHORT $LL6@main
call    end_time
```

Next I compiled the program to use AVX instructions, but this produced the same speed as using SSE. Following is assembly code generated. Also shown is much faster code included in that generated via Linux (GCC with Ubuntu 14.04). Linux speeds were reduced somewhat with a greater number of words but the parameters shown produced SISD type results via Windows.

Note that Windows code is using 128 bit xmm registers but Linux employs 256 bit ymm registers. Does anyone have an explanation of what is going on or suggestions to improve performance using this sample program.

```
Windows AVX                             Linux AVX
Only uses xmm registers                 Part can use ymm registers
                                        Othe parts imcludes xmm
                                        xtra = 1000000; words = 10000; 44271 MFLOPS
call    start_time                      xtra = 10000000; words = 1000; 45653 MFLOPS
npad    6                               SSE
$LL6@main:                               xtra = 1000000; words = 10000; 24492 MFLOPS
mov     rcx, rsi
mov     edx, 125000
npad    8
$LL3@main:                              .L24:
vmovups xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rcx]         vmovaps (%rcx,%rax), %ymm6
lea     rcx, QWORD PTR [rcx+32]         addl    $1, %edx
vmovups xmm5, xmm0                      vaddps  %ymm5, %ymm6, %ymm13
vaddps  xmm1, xmm0, xmm6                vaddps  %ymm3, %ymm6, %ymm7
vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm8                vaddps  %ymm1, %ymm6, %ymm6
vmulps  xmm2, xmm0, xmm9                vmulps  %ymm4, %ymm13, %ymm13
vmulps  xmm3, xmm1, xmm7                vmulps  %ymm2, %ymm7, %ymm7
vsubps  xmm4, xmm3, xmm2                vmulps  %ymm0, %ymm6, %ymm6
vaddps  xmm1, xmm5, xmm10               vsubps  %ymm7, %ymm13, %ymm7
vmulps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm11               vaddps  %ymm6, %ymm7, %ymm6
vaddps  xmm2, xmm4, xmm0                vmovaps %ymm6, (%rcx,%rax)
vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rcx-32], xmm2      addq    $32, %rax
vmovups xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rcx-16]      cmpl    %edx, %esi
vaddps  xmm1, xmm0, xmm6                ja      .L24
vmovups xmm5, xmm0
vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm8
vmulps  xmm2, xmm0, xmm9
vmulps  xmm3, xmm1, xmm7
vaddps  xmm1, xmm5, xmm10
vsubps  xmm4, xmm3, xmm2
vmulps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm11
vaddps  xmm2, xmm4, xmm0
vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rcx-16], xmm2
dec     rdx
jne     SHORT $LL3@main
dec     rbx
jne     $LL6@main
call    end_time
```

Comment: You might want to try the 30 day evaluation of Intel's ICC - it probably does a much better job of vectorizing for AVX than Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio didn't even have auto-vectorization until VS2013. So I'm not surprised that they didn't do the best job on the first version. Clearly it doesn't try to vectorize to 256-bit yet.

Comment: @Mysticial, VS2012 added auto-vectorization.  And according to this video by a compiler developer at MSFT http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/4-587 they have added support for FMA and additional support for AVX in VS2013.  That's actually  quite an interesting video which I think you might like.  They tried FMA everywhere and found it made things worse in many cases.

Comment: @PaulR, why bother with ICC with a 30 day evaluation.  ICC is a mediocre compiler with the best libraries (e.g. MKL).  MinGW-w64 is an excellent compiler with mediocre libraries and it's free.

Comment: I tend to avoid Windows as far as possible, so I don't know all the options, but ICC tends to support newer CPUs better and much sooner than Visual Studio, in my limited experience. On other platforms ICC tends to beat gcc in most cases for SIMD code, again based on my experience. YMMV of course.

Comment: @Zboson VS2013's AVX code-generation is absolutely terrible - a huge regression from VS2012 (even with manually vectorized intrinsics). I have no idea why, but I see it first hand in my app. The FMA code in both VS2012 and VS2013 is embarrassing. The compiler doesn't know how to pick between the 231, 213, and 132 variants. It almost always picks 231 and will issue unnecessary moves. ICC and GCC do much better.

Comment: @PaulR, I agree that ICC is better than Visual Studio for optimization but I have not found ICC to beat GCC for SIMD code in most cases.  I'm surprised you observe that.  I had this problem with ICC a while back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031192/intel-c-compiler-icc-seems-to-ingnore-sse-avx-seetings

Comment: The picture isn't 100% consistent, but over the past ~10 years and umpteen versions of gcc and ICC I've observed that ICC tends to beat gcc in *most* of my benchmarks. In a few cases gcc wins, and in some cases there is little or no difference. gcc has also done a great job of catching up in recent years (and clang is even better), but I have yet to see gcc consistently beat ICC. Nothing stays the same indefinitely though, so I continue to test new versions - maybe one day gcc or clang will be the better choice. (All of the above applies to hand-optimised x86-64 SIMD code using intrinsics.)

Comment: @Mysticial, that's good to know.  I'm no fan of MSVC (I used it since I left academia using linux, gcc, emacs, and bash) I got that video from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710356/how-to-chain-multiple-fma-operations-together-for-performance/23711638#23711638.  Actually, the developer at MSFT makes some strange claims about FMA which I have been meaning to test.